# Showing that there is a $\varphi : U \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $y_0 = \varphi(x_0)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$, $a<b$ and $c<d$. Let $f: (a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$, $g: (c,d)\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions where $g(y)\neq 0$ for $y\in (c,d)$.

Now I have to show that for all $x_0\in (a,b)$ and $y_0\in (c,d)$, there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ and a continuously differentiable function $\varphi : U\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $y_0=\varphi(x_0)$ and:$$\int_{x_0}^{x}f(t) \, dt=\int_{y_0}^{y}g(t) \, dt  \,  \text{ for } \, y=\varphi(x), x\in U$$

**My Idea:**

I feel like it is enough to show  that I can use the implicit function theorem, but I am not sure about all the technicalities that I have to take into account... Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using $F,G$ to denote the anti-derivatives of $f$ and $g$, you have to show that
$$
F(x)-G(y)=F(x_0)-G(y_0)
$$
is locally solvable for $y$. This is done using the implicit function theorem and the appropriately provided properties of $g$.

Comment: Well, I had the right nose then. I am not that familiar with the implicit function theorem, what do you mean by "locally solvable for $y$"?

Comment: It means the existence of a $φ$ ($y=φ(x)$) as described in the claim in your question.

Comment: Hmm, I am really stranded...

Comment: You need, apart from the smoothness assumptions, that $G'(y)\ne 0$, as $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{F'(x)}{G'(y)}=\frac{f(x)}{g(y)}$.

Comment: It is given that $G'(y)=g(y)\neq 0$. What exactly do I have to show?

Comment: Nothing remains to show, no extra argument to find. You have just to put the present facts together in the correct order.

Comment: So I just have to consider the requirements in order to use the implicit function theorem? Could you please elaborate?